# Replace system beep with a pleasant sound?

Tags: sound, command-line

Is it possible to replace System beep with some pleasant sound?

I like having the terminal alert me with a sound rather than a window flash. I prefer to have a pleasant sound because disabling the beep means missing the command completion and its output on terminal.

I prefer to do this using configuration files rather than GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well certainly there's a way to alter that. Here's how you can do that:

```
First collect/download sound files suites your choice.

Open up:

/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo 
/usr/share/sounds/  

Replace the sound files with your downloaded sound files.
```

Remember the name and the extension should be the same.

Comment: And some more *.ogg sounds here: http://gnome-look.org/?xcontentmode=25&PHPSESSID=9c641cbc3d04a4b084c1fff5920c0692 May be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You mean the "alert sound" ?
That would be System Settings > Sound. Here you can choose what you like.

Comment: Can you please point me to the configuration files for this setting instead from GUI?